# Why do passive ETFs require so much trading (and incur costs)?

Tags: financial-literacy, etf, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, rebalancing

As far as I've understood, the idea of passive ETFs is to track an index. Typically, the index is a ***value-weighted*** stock market index, such as the S&P500.

Now, if I'm not mistaken, tracking a value-weighted index is extremely easy - just buy the shares in the exact amount they are in the index and wait. The only time you would need to rebalance your holdings is when there is a change in the index, i.e. a company is dropped and a new one is added, right?

Now, isn't it the case that most stock market indices are revised only a few times per year? If so, why do passive ETFs require frequent rebalancing and generally lose to their benchmark index?

Comment: What evidence do you have that large, well-run, index tracking ETFs "require frequent rebalancing and generally lose to their benchmark index"?  For example, doing a chart comparison between SPY and the S&P500 index shows a faithful tracking of the index.

Comment: My ETFs go as low as .03% expense ratio. $3 per $10,000 invested per year seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps my reasoning was right then? I mean, I am not convinced that tracking an index is as easy as buying and holding, or is it? I remember reading somewhere that even passive tracking requires daily rebalancing (not huge position changes but tiny adjustments) - is this true for some index funds?

Comment: Are you taking into account the fact that an ETF (or any mutual fund) will have investors putting in new money, and sometimes redeeming shares?

Comment: I was not taking that into account. Please explain me the following: since ETF is an exchange traded fund, it means that when I buy one share of the ETF, I can buy it from another investor, correct? Now, how does the ETF manager know whether I own the share or the person who sold it to me owns it? Would it even make a difference to them whether I or someone else owned the share?

Comment: @marty24, you are always buying from another shareholder as only APs would be ones that could exchange underlying securities to get new shares of the fund. I do question how well you get that quarterly outstanding share rebalances are needed as well as handling mergers & acquisitions to keep the number of members in an index correct as the S & P 500 is supposed to have 500 stocks in it which means if one of those gets acquired, a new one may be brought in as well as the owners of the index changing members each month in some cases.

Comment: Note that it is a myth that ETFs always hold the entire index and deal only with APs.  Most ETFs are not structured this way and can hold a subset of the index, use optimization to perturb the portfolio, and sometimes reinvest their dividends.  They don't trade much, but they can and do trade for legitimate reasons.  What they don't normally do is underperform their benchmark, as suggested in the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now, if I'm not mistaken, tracking a value-weighted index is extremely easy - just buy the shares in the exact amount they are in the index and wait.

Yes in theory. In practise this is difficult. Most funds that track S&P do it on sample basis. This is to maintain the fund size. Although I don't have / know the exact number ... if one wants to replicate the 500 stocks in the same %, one would need close to billion in fund size.

As funds are not this large, there are various strategies adopted, including sampling of companies [i.e. don't buy all]; select a set of companies that mimic the S&P behaviour, etc.

All these strategies result in tracking errors. There are algorithms to reduce this.

> The only time you would need to rebalance your holdings is when there is a change in the index, i.e. a company is dropped and a new one is added, right?

So essentially rebalance is done to;

- Mitigate Tracking Errors [Almost daily]
- Change in free float shares, results in change in weight [At times more frequent than quarterly]
- Company dropped and added [generally quarterly]

> If so, why do passive ETFs require frequent rebalancing and generally lose to their benchmark index?

lets take an Index with just 3 companies, with below price.
The total Market cap is 1000

[image: Index with just 3 companies]

The Minimum required to mimic this index is 200 or Multiples of 200. If so you are fine.

[image: Minimum Fund Value]

More Often, funds can't be this large. For example approx 100 funds track the S&P Index. Together they hold around 8-10% of Market Cap. Few large funds like Vangaurd, etc may hold around 2%. But most of the 100+ S&P funds hold something in 0.1 to 0.5 range.

So lets say a fund only has 100. To maintain same proportion it has to buy shares in fraction. But it can only buy shares in whole numbers. This would then force the fund manager to allocate out of proportion, some may remain cash, etc. As you can see below illustrative, there is a tracking error. The fund is not truly able to mimic the index.

[image: Fund allocation with 100]

Now lets say after 1st April, the share price moved, now this would mean more tracking error if no action is taken [block 2] ... and less tracking error if one share of company B is sold and one share of company C is purchased.

[image: Price Change and Tracking error]

Again the above is a very simplified view. Tracking error computation is involved mathematics.

Now that we have the basic concepts, more often funds tracking S&P;

- don't buy all stocks.
- don't buy in same proportion.

Thus they need to rebalance.

Comment: @marty24 I agree that Dheer's answer is indeed comprehensive.  The short version is that index funds use a weighted index which takes into account that shares from the companies on the list vary according to number of shares and price per share.  A well set up index fund will leave room for variance, but will rebalance to maintain the (weighted) index.  I.e. they'll set a range for each individual holding and allow each to remain 'as-is' within that range.  But when it is outside the range at reconciliation time, shares are bought or sold to bring it back in the range.